# Squish test functions always pass when used with squishtest module

Tags: python, squish

We are using Squish for Qt 6.6.2 on Windows 10 with Python 3.8.7 and running our tests using `squishtest` module with Robot Framework 4.0.1.

We are having an issue with the `test` functions provided by the Squish API where any verifications done with such a call (for example `squishtest.test.imagePresent`) will Pass. The issue itself was quite simple to pinpoint to the fact that although the verification failed, the function call itself was passing without raising exceptions. This can also be verified from the report provided by the squishrunner where we have `<scriptedVerificationResult type="FAIL" time="--">` on the passed execution.

The question is, can we in any way get the actual verification result passed to the Robot so we can fail the test accordingly? Preferrably in real time rather than parsing the report afterwards.

In Squish this works perfectly fine

```py
def main():
    startApplication("AUT")
    snooze(2)
    test.imagePresent("image.png", {"tolerant": True, "threshold": 85}, 
    waitForObjectExists(names.sceneContainer_GraphWidget))
```

but with Robot this is always passing

```
# In testSuite.robot

*** Settings ***
Library     MySquishLib

*** Test Cases ***
Test Image
    Start AUT
    Verify Image    image.png    {"tolerant": True, "threshold": 85}    names.sceneContainer_GraphWidget
```

```py
# In MySquishLib.py

import squishtest
import names

def start_aut():
    squishtest.startApplication("AUT")

def verify_image(imageFile, imageParams, imageArea):
    squishtest.test.imagePresent(imageFile, imageParams, imageArea)
```

Comment: test.imagePresent() is not documented to throw an error. For me, your low tolerance threshold causes the addressbook main window to be "found" even when it is actually not on the screen. I cannot reproduce the problem while using the squishtest module. test.imagePresent() returns true or false as expected for me. Can you reproduce the problem when using squishtest without the Robot framework?

Comment: My wording may have been a bit unclear, but that was exactly the point of this question. I would like the function call to either A) Return the status of the VP or B) throw error on failed VP. At first I expected the tolerance to be an issue as well but as mentioned, in the ``results.xml`` created by Squish, the VP has passed/failed just as expected.

Comment: @frog.ca The "issue" was actually in the fact that, as you can see from the question, I'm actually not using the return value anywhere. As you pointed out - The function does return bool value correctly and is not supposed to raise exception. Additionally, the outcome can be found during runtime from the ``results.xml``. If using ``xml3`` report, the values can be already accessed there before the test ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `test` functions are not supposed to raise exceptions during execution in order to allow test to continue even if a single VP was failed. The function does however return a boolean value just as expected. By using

```
def verify_image(imageFile, imageParams, imageArea):
    if not squishtest.test.imagePresent(imageFile, imageParams, imageArea):
        raise Exception("Image was not found")
```

I'm able to fail the Robot test without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documented: `bool testSettings.throwOnFailure` flag.
In your robot you can set this and you would not have to patch / rewrite every `test.vp`, `test.compare`, ... method.

When running from within the Squish IDE, this flag can be unset. Probably `robotframework` provides some environment variables to detect wether the test case is running from within itself.

https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#rgs-testsettings